# Введение URL c текстового поля

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Есть текстовое поле tf1 и есть строка кода

```
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:NSURL URLWithString:@"qwe"]
               cashePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCashePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
```

Как сделать, чтобы вместо `qwe` там было то что ввел пользователь в `tf1`? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Sergey4590, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                             [NSURL URLWithString: [tf1 stringValue]] 
                                     cashePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCashePolicy
                                 timeoutInterval: 15.0];
```